# Exporting index table from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb, database-indexes

I am recently working on better indexing concepts. as part of that, I want to know if it is possible to export the index table that mysql generates internally. I want to be able to export the index table in the form of CSV.

I am aware about creating the index in the database with:

```
Example : CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_list)
```

After the index has been made, i am able to see it with:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table_name;
```

In phpmyadmin i am able to see the index table in the structure section.

I am using InnoDB engine and For InnoDB engine, the indexes are stored in the tablespace, along with the table. If innodb_file_per_table option is set, the indexes will be in the table's .ibd file.

so will it be possible to export index table data in a form of csv from .ibd file ?

I want to export the index table that mysql generates internally, in a CSV format.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
PRIMARY KEY (id),
INDEX(a,b)
```

Then

```
SELECT a, b, id INTO outfile ... FROM ... ORDER BY a,b,id
```

will give you the contents of the index.  It will not, however, show you any details of the B+Tree that is the overhead of the `INDEX`.

The `PRIMARY KEY` of a InnoDB table is a B+Tree with all the columns in PK order.

The "secondary key" (Unique or not) is a B+Tree with all the columns of the secondary index, plus any other columns from the PK.  It is also sorted.

Prefix indexes (eg, `INDEX(foo(7))`) are another matter.

`FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` have their own internal structure, not a straightforward B+Tree.